# How to use "this" of class in "callbacks" in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm using Babel with ES2015. And want to use `this` inside `callback` inside method.

```
class baz {
  bar = "xxx";
  foo() {
    x(function() {
      console.log(this.bar);
    });
  }
}

function x(callback) {
  return callback();
}
var y = new baz();
y.foo();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dnthehnt/7/
I'm getting

> TypeError: this is undefined

because as far as I understand this refers to the callback function in `x()`. As a solution I use

```
class baz {
  bar = "xxx";
  foo() {
    var bar = this.bar;//<=====
    x(function() {
      console.log(bar);//<=====
    });
  }
}

function x(callback) {
  return callback();
}
var y = new baz();
y.foo();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dnthehnt/6/ 
And get

> xxx

This is solution, but if you have mass of code it's getting very confusing and hard to write. Is there any better solution for using `this`? Or any other discipline for ES6 for using callbacks and this.

Comment: That's not valid ES2015. It's invalid as of the second line (`bar = "xxx";`). You'd need A) To put that code in `constructor() { /*...*/ }` and B) To use `this.` in front of `bar`.

Comment: I think putting in ```constructor``` is not necessary. I think it'll be better to put in constructor variables which will be added on initialization.

Comment: It's not a matter of "thinking" one way or another. That code is not valid ES2015 code. There is a [Stage 1 proposal](https://github.com/jeffmo/es-class-fields-and-static-properties) for allowing instance fields to be defined that way, but it's just Stage 1 (there are stages 0 through 4, where 4 is "ready to include in the next spec"). It didn't make the ES2016 spec cutoff, and unless it progresses faster, looking iffy for ES2017. So while Babel may transpile it (Babel has many non-standard features), the syntax could well change before it's put in the spec, leaving you with nonstandard code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look into arrow functions, and especially the way `this` is handled by arrow functions in comparison to classic functions.

```
class baz {
  constructor() { this.bar = "xxx"; }
  foo() {
    x(() => {
      console.log(this.bar);
    });
  }
}
```

Your solution using classic functions would not work if bar was changed between the call to `x` and the call to the callback.

This is how you should do it with classic functions

```
class baz {
  constructor() { this.bar = "xxx"; }
  foo() {
    const self = this;
    x(function () {
      console.log(self.bar);
    });
  }
}
```

Or you could use `bind`, I suppose.

```
class baz {
  constructor() { this.bar = "xxx"; }
  foo() {
    x((function () {
      console.log(this.bar);
    }).bind(this));
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, thank you, you're right. I forgot that ()=>{}  has no prototype.

Comment: @Shekspir: It has nothing whatsoever to do with prototypes. Arrow functions have no `this` binding, so they inherit it from the context where they're created.